# How to check React build folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bash, create-react-app

I'm using `create-react-app` to build my project.

I'm trying to implement a health checker bash command to see if javascript bundle files are correctly built. Currently, I'm just testing if js files are there inside `build/static/js` by creating a JSON file that holds all js file names inside of it.

I'm still not sure if that's a good way or not.

Is there any way to check all files that are created inside the `build` folder are okay?

Comment: what is exactly what you want to test? The fact that the `build` target runs correctly is already a sign that `create-react-app` thinks it succeeded, so the question is what extra tests would you like to have on top of that?

Comment: @MarioF Yes actually. I want to be able to test the built files from an external system.

Comment: yes, but what do you want to test? That they exist? That they contain something in particular?